# Ссылка на ячейку через значение другой ячейки

Tags: excel

Нужно, чтобы ячейка ссылалась на другую ячейку, которая определяется числом в третьей ячейке, типа такого:

```
Ячейка A = x
Ячейка B: ссылается на $D$x
```

теперь меняя значение ячейки A получаем различные ссылки в B.

Возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов много в зависимости от того, что вам нужно, например:

```
[A1]=INDEX(C1:F1;1;B1) // ИНДЕКС
```

Меняя номер колонки в `B1` от 1 до 4, в ячейке `A1` получаем значение одной из ячеек дипазона `C1:F1`.

Или:

```
[C3]=INDIRECT("A"&B3) .. // ДВССЫЛ
```

Меняя номер строки в `B3` от 1 до максимума, в ячейке `C3` получаем значение одной из ячеек колонки `A`.

Или:

```
[С4]=OFFSET(D5;C5;C6) // СМЕЩ
```

Меняя смещение по строкам в `C5` от -максимума до +максимума и по колонкам в `C6` от -максимума до +максимума, в ячейке `C4` получаем значение ячейки, смещенной от `D5` на указанное количество строк и колонок.

Comment: Для диапазона, в котором одна строка или однин столбец, параметр можно не указывать: `=INDEX(C1:F1;B1)`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте =[ДВССЫЛ](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)("$D$" & $A$1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]